# 401 response code for HttpURLConnection sending POST with custom header

Tags: java

I am trying to send a POST command to an api

```
private static JsonNode postToServer(String query, String json) throws IOException
{

    URL url = new URL(query);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "BLN");
    conn.setRequestProperty("type", "api");
    conn.setRequestProperty("version", "1");
    conn.setRequestProperty("entity", "network");
    conn.setRequestProperty("key", NETWORK_KEY);
    conn.setRequestProperty("token", TOKEN);
    conn.setRequestProperty("secret", SECRET);

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream())
    {
        os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    JsonNode jsonObject;
    try ( // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()))
    {
        String result = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonObject = mapper.readTree(result);
    }
    conn.disconnect();

    return jsonObject;
}
```

The API docs shows an example header:

`Authorization: BLN type=api, version=1, entity=network, key=”my-learner”, token=31fec415d80b9d5e924787f783e99b, secret=671441b158c7256c5c8d6f3c0abb647ae`

I'm getting a response code:
`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401`

Am I setting up the headers correctly?

Comment: For `conn.setRequestProperty("network", NETWORK_KEY);`, do you want this to be `conn.setRequestProperty("key", NETWORK_KEY);`?

Comment: darn...I was hoping that was the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to snippet from documentation you shared in question, you should do something like

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "BLN type=api, version=1, entity=network, key=”my-learner”, token=31fec415d80b9d5e924787f783e99b, secret=671441b158c7256c5c8d6f3c0abb647ae");
```

It's single header.